# addPlayer() method returns no value

Tags: java

I am writing code to sort out a charity football team, I am to write a method called addPlayer() that takes two string arguements, players name and if celeb or professional and a char argument for gender. The method returns no value. This method creates a new instance of Player with the given name, classification and gender and adds it to the appropriate collection of players either celeb or prof.

I have a populatePlayerLists() method

```
public void populatePlayerLists()
{

   this.addPlayer("Robbie Williams","Celebrity",'M');
   this.addPlayer("Robbie Fowler","Professional",'M');

}
```

my instance variables are as follows

```
private List < Player > professionalsList;
private List< Player > celebritiesList;
```

and my addPlayer() method is as follows

```
public void addPlayer(String name, String classification,char gender)
{

   { 
      this.professionalsList.add(new Player(name, classification, gender)); 
      this.celebritiesList.add(new Player(name, classification, gender)); 
   } 
}
```

The players and celebs add to the lists but they add to both lists, when i want the celebs to goto one list and pros goto the other help please.

Answer (score 5):

You can this String system and check the value of the string with a `equals()`.

```
Player player = new Player(name, classification, gender);
if (classification.equals("Celebrity")) {
   this.celebritiesList.add(player);
} else if (classification.equals("Professional"))
   this.professionalsList.add(player); 
}
```

---

Or you can change your system to use enums (way, way better) :

```
public enum Classification{
    Professional,
    Celebrity;
}

public enum Gender{
    Male,
    Female;
}

public void addPlayer(String name, Classification classification, Gender gender){ 
    Player player = new Player(name, classification, gender);
    if (classification == Classification.Celebrity) {
       this.celebritiesList.add(player);
    } else if (classification == Classification.Professional){
       this.professionalsList.add(player); 
    }
}

//...    
this.addPlayer("Robbie Williams", Classification.Celebrity, Gender.Male);
this.addPlayer("Robbie Fowler", Classification.Professional, Gender.Male);
```

---

You can even use `switch` (but I wouldn't use it) :

```
Player player = new Player(name, classification, gender);
switch(classification){
    case Celebrity : 
        this.celebritiesList.add(player);
        break;
    case Professional : 
        this.professionalsList.add(player);
        break;
    default :
        System.out.println("FileNotFound");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

simple if statment will do it:

```
public void addPlayer(String name, String classification,char gender)
{
    if (classification.equals("Professional"))
        this.professionalsList.add(new Player(name, classification, gender));
    else
        this.celebritiesList.add(new Player(name, classification, gender)); 
}
```

or

```
public void addPlayer(String name, String classification,char gender)
{
    if (classification.equals("Professional"))
        this.professionalsList.add(new Player(name, classification, gender));
    else if (classification.equals("Celebrity"))
        this.celebritiesList.add(new Player(name, classification, gender)); 
    else
        throw new RuntimeException("unknown classification: " + classification);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're missing the logic to choose which list to add to?  Something like

```
if (classification.equals("Celebrity")) {
   this.celebritiesList.add(new Player(name, classification, gender));
} else {
   this.professionalsList.add(new Player(name, classification, gender)); 
}
```